# Weird behavior of height parameter in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is what i am doing in my layout

```
  h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); 


Relative Layout = 60 dp = 90 using .getHeight()
Relative Layout = wrap content

Relative layout align bottom = 60 dp = 90
```

Now my width and height variables are showing height of 800.

I am doing following things

```
h = h - 180 // 

for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            LayoutParams params  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w/10, h/10);

            wordsLayout.addView(tv,params);
}
```

I have made the code so that each `textView` goes directly below first one. Now according to code, the remaining height after subtracting heights of relative layouts should make the height of all `textviews` so that they fill up the empty space.

However this works fine for w/10 or width but for height it always takes more space than empty space. I can't understand what is happening. How to adjust the height so that it only fills the space

Comment: Have you considered setting the views and layouts in your XML file? Also, for your question, try adding weight to the views. For example, if you have 2 buttons and you wanted them to both be side by side with equal lengths. Add 0.50 weight to both of them and you will have both of them fill up all the spaces in pretty much all devices (depending on the height you give them)

Comment: i am actually adding 144 textviews in android. just like a crossword thing. i want this crossword to fill up in the remaining path

Comment: also each textview height is equal and is according to my calculation but it seems like h = 800 is wrong? check the edited version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I was missing the fact that the `title bar` takes some height of the screen too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making all of them weighted with the same weight:

```
LayoutParams params  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w/10, h/10,(float) 1.0);
```